# Filter unique items from jQuery array

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pull all unique `Field` names from the returned results of an Ajax call. However, for whatever reason, the `Field` name `DRMrole` continues to appear twice.

Here is the jQuery I am using

```
//Construct array to determine unique Field names
var fieldArray = [];
$.each(data, function(i, item){
    fieldArray.push(item.Field);
    console.log(item.Field);
});
fieldArray = $.unique(fieldArray);
console.log(fieldArray);
```

And here are the readouts from the `console.log` commands

[image]

As you can see, for some reason `DRMrole` appears twice in the filtered results. This happens each and every time I run this code so doesn't appear to be random.

Comment: Can you compare their lengths as well? There might be a hidden character in there.

Comment: Per the `$.unique` documentation: "Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers."

Comment: Check to see if the value is already in the array using $.inArray before pushing the value? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: `jQuery.unique(array)` will return unique items.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could always use an object instead of an array - placing each item as a property in the object. Each identical key that you attempted to insert would simple override the existing one:

```
var fieldArray = {}; // object instead of array
$.each(data, function(i, item){
    fieldArray[item.Field] = item.Field;
});
```

Here is a **super simple** [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5a6s/)

---

Another option (as mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491201/filter-unique-items-from-jquery-array/16491239#comment23668657_16491201) by [sbeliv01](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634752/sbeliv01)) would be to use the `$.inArray()` function to test if an element already exists:

```
var fieldArray = [];
$.each(data, function(i, item){
  if ($.inArray(item.Field,fieldArray) === -1){
    fieldArray.push(item.Field);
  }
});
```

Reference - [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Comment: You rock, thanks for the help. FYI though - the second example w/`$.inArray` doesn't work for some reason. I wind up with a blank array in `fieldArray`

Comment: Oops - yea.. Take a look at the parameters I gave to `$.inArray`.. I placed `item` instead of `item.Field`...

Comment: `$.inArray(item.Field,fieldArray) === -1` instead

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you already have an array that you'd like to "uniqueinize"

```
Array.prototype.getUnique = function(){
   var u = {}, a = [];
   for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i){
      if(u.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) {
         continue;
      }
      a.push(this[i]);
      u[this[i]] = 1;
   }
   return a;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

var x = [2, 3, 6, 3, 2, 5];

x = x.filter(function(a,b,c){ return c.indexOf(a,- c.length) >= b ? true :false ; });